# Is it possible to put this np.where function in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to move all values in the data frame that contains "Applicant Age" data (there is only one "Applicant Age" value per row) into a new column "applicant_age", but there are 17 columns that I have to iterate over to find them - the data is all mixed up at the moment.

```
df_merged['applicant_age'] = np.where(df_merged.rule0_evaluationstring.str.contains('Applicant Age'), 
                                           df_merged['rule0_evaluationstring'],
                                           df_merged['applicant_age'])
```

I'm using an np.where function, and it is giving me the desired result, but now I have to change the number in "rule0_evaluationstring" from 0 - 16 to go through all 17 columns.

Is there a loop that I can use to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your code in a `for` loop would look like this:

```py
for i in range(17):
    rule_col = f'rule{i}_evaluationstring'
    matches = df_merged[rule_col].str.contains('Applicant Age')
    df_merged['applicant_age'] = np.where(matches, df_merged[rule_col], df_merged['applicant_age'])
```

BTW, Instead of using `np.where`, I think it's slightly more idiomatic to select the rows via pandas syntax:

```
for i in range(17):
    rule_col = f'rule{i}_evaluationstring'
    matches = df_merged[rule_col].str.contains('Applicant Age')
    df_merged.loc[matches, 'applicant_age'] = df_merged.loc[matches, rule_col]
```